Was Balarama included in the list of Dashavatara in any scripture instead of Buddha?
I heard that Balarama was also considered one of the Dashavataras (instead of Buddha). However, I am not aware of any scripture that included Balarama in the lists of Dashavatara. This post lists Dashavataras according to many Puranas. All the lists include Buddha, not Balarama.
But many Hindus consider Balarama as one of the Dashavataras. A recent Bengali movie (Durgeshgarer Guptadhan) also lists Balarama instead of Buddha. Does this belief have any scriptural support or is it just a popular belief?

Balarama is said to be the 8th Avatar by Jayadeva in his Dashavatara Stotra where he glorifies the ten incarnations and considers Kesava [Krishna] as their origin.
Ten Avataras according to Dashavatara Stotra are as follows: Fish, Tortoise, Boar, Man-Lion, Dwarf Brahmin, Parasurama, Rama, Balarama, Buddha, and Kalki.
The Dashavatara Stotra is accepted as a scriptural authority by the Gaudiya Vaishnavas as well as the followers of Lord Jagannath of Orissa.

vahasi vapushi visade vasanam jaladabham
hala-hati-bhiti-milita-yamunabham
kesava dhrita-haladhara-rupa jaya jagadisa hare

0 Kesava! O Lord of the universe! O Lord Hari, who have assumed the
form of Balarama, the wielder of the plow! All glories to You! On Your
brilliant white body You wear garments the color of a fresh blue rain
cloud. These garments are colored like the beautiful dark hue of the
River Yamuna, who feels great fear due to the striking of Your
plowshare.

Buddha is also an incarnation as per Jayadeva:
nindasi yajna-vidher ahaha sruti-jatam sadaya-hridaya
darsita-pasu-ghatam kesava dhrita-buddha-sarira jaya jagadisa hare


O Kesava! O Lord of the universe! O Lord Hari, who have assumed the
form of Buddha! All glories to You! O Buddha of compassionate heart,
you decry the slaughtering of poor animals performed according to the
rules of Vedic sacrifice.

Related: Reason for the slight differences in the 10 avatars.

Please add the list of ten avataras according to the dashavatara stotra. If Buddha and Balarama both are included, then who is not part of the list? Someone must be removed to make it ten, otherwise it would be 11.

Where is Krishna???? Krishna is missing from the list! Very strange!!!

Keshava (Krishna) is the origin of the ten avataras.

I would be citing some śāstriya references here, which list Balarāma in Viṣṇu's daśāvatāras.

Matsya, Kūrma, Varāha, Nṛsiṁha, Vāmana, Paraśurāma, Rāma, Balarāma, Buddha, & Kalki.

matsyaḥ kūrmo varāhaśca narasiṁho'tha vāmanaḥ / 
rāmo rāmaśca rāmaśca buddhaḥ kalkīti te daśa // 
~  Śānti Parva (348.2), Mahābhārata Kumbhaghoṇa recension



In this list, Kṛṣṇa isn't mentioned among the daśāvatāras, similar to the Daśāvatāra list given in the 1st prabandha of Jayadeva's Gītagovinda, which is accepted by Gauḍīyas. But there's another list, in which Balarāma & Kṛṣna are present and Buddha is absent.
Taking Balarāma instead of Buddha in the daśāvatāra list, is a pakṣa strongly held by Śrī Vaiṣṇavas, so I would be referring two such works from the sampradāya ahead.

Matsya, Kūrma, Varāha, Narasiṁha, Vāmana, Paraśurāma, Rāma, Balarāma, Kṛṣṇa, & Kalki.

icchā mīna vihāra kacchapa mahā potrīn yadṛcchā hare 
rakṣā vāmana roṣa rāma karuṇā kākutstha helā halin / 
krīḍā vallava kalka vāhana daśā kalkinniti pratyahaṁ 
jalpantaḥ puruṣāḥ punanti bhuvanaṁ puṇyaugha paṇyāpaṇāḥ // 
~ Daśāvatāra stotram (12) by Veṅkaṭanātha (Vedānta Deśika)


Matsya, Kūrma, Varāha, Nṛsiṁha, Vāmana, Paraśurāma, Rāma, Balarāma, Kṛṣṇa, & Kalki.

tatra vedāpahāridaityanirasanadvārā brahmaṇe pramāṇapadatvārtham avatīrṇo matsyāvatāraḥ / devānām ajarāmṛtihetvamṛtotpādane mandarādhāratvena avatīrṇaḥ kūrmāvatarāḥ / saṁsārasāgaronmagnajanoddhartukāmaḥ svamahiṣībhūmyuddharaṇārtham avatīrṇo varāhāvatāraḥ / āśritasaṁrakṣaṇārthaṁ mahāsuragrahastambhe'vatīrṇo nṛsiṁhāvatāraḥ /
trivikramo bhūtvā svapādāravindodbhavena jalena jagatpāpaharaṇena tadrakṣaṇārtham avatīrṇo vāmanāvatāraḥ / duṣṭakṣattriyanirasanārthaṁ paraśurāmaḥ / śaraṇāgatarakṣaṇārtho dharmasthāpanārthaḥ śrīrāma pralambādinirasanārthaṁ balabhadraḥ / mokṣopāyadarśanārthaṁ śrīkṛṣṇa / adharmiṣṭhānnirasya pūrṇadharmotpādanārthaṁ kalinirmocanārthaṁ kalkyavatāraḥ / evamekaikāvatāreṣvanantaprakārāḥ santi /
~ Yatīndramatadīpikā (9) by Śrīnivāsadāsa




what is kumbhagona recension of mahabharata?

It's a Southern recension of Mahābhārata, which is a bit different than the popular Northern recension, that is followed by Nīlakaṇṭha's comm. Bhāratabhāvadīpa.  @AmritenduMukhopadhyay
